# Creating Chat box using sockets in PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pyqt, pyqt4

i am trying to create a chat application using web sockets in Pyqt. I have tried using threads but still facing error--QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x11c8730), parent's thread is QThread(0x1148b50), current thread is listener(0x11b6a40)

My code for client is:

http://pastebin.com/XfUsXN86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.*

When using QT and multithreading you must ensure you don't interact with the GUI from another thread except for GUI thread. Queue events to GUI's thread to do it.

You can use connect and emmit to do it: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/

You may be having this issue at *line 78*:

`window.browser.setText(data)`

Comment: @liezek i hv done connect and emit bt this time it is crashing without error..can u check the code again plz..i need this badly...http://pastebin.com/j5vSbNTJ

Comment: You are reading twice from socket, at lines 88 and 65. By the way, if the bug you asked for is fixed with my answer, you should check it for valid answer and ask again.